# Grey out form button on touch start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a input of type 'button' with a background and was wondering how I would grey out the background through javascript. The css for it looks like this:

```
background:url(../img/cameraPic.png) no-repeat center;
```

When someone touches it I want it to respond by greying out while it's being held down. The skeleton for such a function would look like this but I'm not sure how to change the color when it has background.

```
 $("#myButton").bind('touchstart', function(e){
     //...What to put here?      
 });
```

Does anybody have any ideas? Should I use a grayscale() css property or just make a new image and replace the background with the new image every time its being pressed?

Comment: Try it and see how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? [Example](http://jsbin.com/juyegu/edit?html,js,output)

```
 $("button").bind('touchstart', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).css({
     'background-color':'grey',
     opacity:0.3
   });

 });

$("button").bind('touchend', function(e){

   $(this).css({
     'background-color':'transparent',
     opacity:1
   });

 });
```

Comment: So you're putting a semi-transparent grey layer over the image here I see?

Comment: @MarksCode yes, if I understand right, that is something like behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: Yes doesn't seem to be working, the background is still the same image

Comment: @MarksCode edited code, you can see the example, but made with `mousedown` and `up`

Comment: Why does background-color need to be in quotation marks but opacity does not?

Comment: @MarksCode because of  the variable conflict, you can store the bck color in some variable, and set in there. If there is no quotation marks, JS will think that grey is some variable, which is undefined.